# Maximize the trace subject to a. normalization constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, data-analysis

Assuming that $A$ is symmetric , V an arbitary unitary matrice and   $B$ positive definite. I need to maximize $Tr[V^T A V]$  subject to a normalization constraint for V , one that requires that $V$ be B-orthogonal (i.e $V^T BV=I)$.

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\max _{V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}} & \operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T} A V\right] \\
V^{T} B V=I
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a square matrix such that $B = M^TM$ ($M$ can be attained, for instance, with a Cholesky decomposition). With the substitution $U = MV$, we can rewrite the maximization problem as
$$
\begin{cases}
\max_{U \in \Bbb R^{n \times d}}\operatorname{Tr}[U^T[M^{-T}AM^{-1}]U]\\
U^TU = I.
\end{cases}
$$
Conclude that the maximum is the sum of the $d$ largest eigenvalues of $M^{-T}AM^{-1}$. Note that these are equal to the eigenvalues of $M^{-1}M^{-T}A = B^{-1}A$. In other words, the maximum will be the $d$ largest eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A$.

Comment: Why we use specifically cholesky decomposition?

Comment: There is no particular need to use the Cholesky decomposition, hence "for instance".

Comment: In Cholesky decomposition I think M should be a upper triangular matrix? and why you pose the subsitution $U=MV$?

Comment: I don't understand your question about the Cholesky decomposition. The point of the substitution is that if $V$ is a $B$-orthogonal matrix, then $U$ is an orthogonal matrix. By reframing the problem in terms of an orthogonal matrix, I reduce the problem to one whose solution is known.

Comment: The Cholesky decomposition :every positive definite matrix $B$ can be factored as $B=M^T M$ where M is upper triangular with positive diagonal elements. In your answer you take M just as a square matrix??

Comment: @mouadlmazini The only requirement for the purposes of my answer is that $M$ is square. One way to obtain such a matrix is to use the Cholesky decomposition. The Cholesky decomposition also happens to give you a matrix $M$ that is upper triangular, but this fact is not relevant to my usage of it.